# Drupal - edit a form without a hook_form_alter?

Tags: forms, drupal, drupal-7

Here is my problem :
I have a checkout page with multiple forms, the first one is for add people to the order, and the second one is the checkout form. I need to get the people from the first form in my second form, the problem is that these two forms are created when the page is loaded, so at the beggining the second form doesn't know who are the people in the first form, so I can't use form_alter (or only if I refresh the page).

I think the thing to do is add them when the first form is submitted, but how to alter fields of another form ?

Edit:

Yes same page, so i really can't use the form_alter, I try this thing now : `ajax_command_replace('#commerce-checkout-form', drupal_render(drupal_get_form('commerce-checkout-form', $order, $payment_page)));`
 but the drupal_render returns me an empty form (I check with dsm) and it's not replaced in the page

I also try to set a callback on my checkbox field and do a form_rebuild on the callback but doesn't work too... I really don't know how to do that

Do you have any idea of how to make this works ?

Comment: Save the people when the first form is submitted (session?), use this session data to alter the second form. Just a thought off the top of my head. You have not told us what drupal version you are using. Maybe add the tag.

Comment: I added the tag, how can I alter the second form ? He's on the same page of the first one so I can't use the hook_form_alter, and I need to alter it after the first one is submitted (it's an ajax submit, but not me who make it)

Comment: oh, the same page... are you sure both parts cant be altered via the one hook_form_alter ? If not, then maybe you have to do your manipulation via a javascript `drupal.behavior`.

Comment: Look at my edit please